# how to use additional partition space for downloading upates

Tags: update-manager, synaptic

Generally I use synaptic package manager (sometimes software updater) for downloading and updates, which is automatic.  However while downloading I get a warning for not available space in / partition - though I have enough space under another partition, which is also mounted in /mnt directory.  How I can tell Synaptic Package Manager / Sofware manager to use the space available in /mnt directory (a separate partition) or alternative how I can move my installed applications to that partition?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at it the other way around: find your personal files and put those on the 2nd disk. Since it is a /mnt it will be external, if it is ntfs it is useless for Linux except for storing your personal files. The Linux system itself needs it to be ext.

Don't move /home/ itself to an external partition. You can also link the directories in /home/ to the external disk (move the normal directories in /home/$USER/ to the external disk and from command line do `ln -s Desktop /mnt/Desktop` for every directory and after doing Desktop press F5 on your desktop; the icons should refresh). Make sure though the external disk is  mounted during boot otherwise you will see nothing on your desktop.

If you still lack space after moving documents and downloads from for instance /home/ to that partition it might be worth while investing in a bigger or a second internal hard disk.